# DDD - Modificar mais de um aggregate na mesma transação

Tags: eventos, ddd, domínio

Sou iniciante em DDD e me deparei com uma situação envolvendo a regra de não modificar mais de 1 aggregate na mesma transação, usando Domain Events para resolver alterações em outros aggregates. (vide [Effective Agregate Design](https://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/)).

A situação é a seguinte: O usuário agenda a transferência de um paciente para outra unidade. Quando chega a hora da transferência, o usuário a seleciona numa lista e clica 'iniciar'. Porém essa ação acarreta mudanças em três aggregates (processo levantado junto ao cliente):

- Transferência: é marcada como iniciada. ex: transferencia.Iniciar();
- Paciente: é marcado como em transferência. ex: paciente.MarcarComoEmTransferencia();
- Unidade: deve reservar uma vaga para o paciente que agora está por vir. ex: unidade.ReservarVaga(paciente);

Assim que a transferência é iniciada, é emitido um evento TransferenciaIniciada. Também neste momento a equipe está autorizada a iniciá-la. 
Mas, se por algum motivo, a equipe inicia a transferência, mas ocorre um erro ao tratar o evento TransferenciaIniciada, por exemplo, ao mudar o status do paciente ou reservar vaga no destino, como devo lidar com essa situação, visto que a equipe já pode estar no meio transferência?

Lembrando que estou seguindo a regra de uma transação por aggregate.

Answer (score -1):

Primeiramente é importante você definir a ordem com que os eventos ocorrem. Será que iniciar a transferência deve ocorrer antes da reserva? Não deveria haver uma verificação de vaga antes? Dito isso, ao meu ver, reservar a vaga deve vir antes da transferência.

Com a vaga reservada, o usuário pode receber uma notificação de que a transferência pode ser iniciada ou um evento pode ser emitido para um assinante iniciar a transferência.

O segundo caso - paciente em transferência - pode ocorrer mediante o evento de transferência iniciada. O publicador de eventos deve saber lidar com possíveis falhas na entrega da mensagem. Isso vai depender do message broker que você está usando. A maioria tem uma feature pra lidar com isso. A mais comum é adicionar a mensagem com falha em uma fila de retentativas.

É importante também você verificar se não há um erro na modelagem dos limites transacionais dos dois agregados. A necessidade de manipular dois ou mais agregados dentro de uma mesma transação pode ser um indício de que há falhas nos seus limites de consistência.